# const vector<T> * which part is const?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

```
int* test_prt(const vector<int>* array, const int index)
{
    return array+index;
}
```

why the first argument can't be **const** ? under this circumstance, the "const" means what can not be modified?

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass that `std::vector` as a pointer?

Comment: Won't compile: `array+index` has the same type as `array` and can't be converted to the return type `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

It is common to place `const` after the type name, because it enables the "const to the left rule".

This is the same as what you wrote:

```
int* test_prt(vector<int> const* array, const int index)
{
    return array+index;
}
```

Here, the item to the left is the vector, so this is a pointer to constant vector.

If you don't use this convention, the only special case is when `const` is all the way on the left (there is nothing to the left of const), which means it applies to the thing immediately to the right of the `const`.

Comment: The rule-of-thumb is `const` applies to the thing to the left of it.  If there is nothing to the left of it, it applies to the leftmost thing.

Comment: so in this case, what the pointer point to can not be modified, but the pointer itself can move?

Comment: @nzomkxia, Yes, though since it isn't, I'd recommend making it `const` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`array + index` is not modifying either `array` or `index`, it simply computes the sum between the two operands without affecting the original, so the code is working as it's supposed to. The `const` here means that both the vector and `index` cannot change in any way. For example, if I attempt to change one of `array`s elements, I get an error:

```
array[0] = 5; // error! assignment of read-only value
```

The same applies to `index`. By the way, I think your function signature should have been written as:

```
int* test_prt(const vector<int>& array, const int index)
{
    return &array[index];
    // or &array.at(index) which performs bounds checking
}
```

That is, we take the vector by reference and use an offset from the first element pointed to by its internal buffer. Taking by reference is essential as it avoids a copy and returning a pointer to a local copy would be Undefined Behavior. Your original code would have only worked if `array` was an actual array of vectors!

And just to be clear, here's how you would call the function:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::cout << test_ptr(v, 1); // prints the address of the 2nd element
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also remove the "const" in front of the integer.
As it's an arg passed by value,

```
int* test_prt(vector<int> const* array, int index)
{
     return array+index;
 }
```